# Getting POST arguments sent with a HTML form in C++

Tags: c++, html, apache

I am developing a program in C++ which is associated to open an URL with a personal protocol (it is similar to mailto protocol).
I can recover GET arguments with `argv[1]`, but what is for POST arguments ?

I read [this page](http://www.openroad.org/cgihelp/cgi.html) but it is for CGI programs, whereas mine is client side.

**EDIT:**
@Krishnanunni :
I thought the same but I get these results.
With `method="GET"`:

```
argv[0] = C:\Program Files\MySoftware\transferMail.exe
argv[1] = myproto:?to=&bcc=contact@test.com&subject=You%20are%20testing%20something%20new&attachment=&body=
```

And with `method="POST"` :

```
argv[0] = C:\Program Files\MySoftware\transferMail.exe
argv[1] = myproto:
```

My loop isn't very hard :

```cpp
for(int i=0; i < argc; ++i) {
  cout << "argv[" << i << "] = " << argv[i] << endl;
}
```

Comment: Same should do. GET/POST are methods Browser level(newtowrk/Transport). I think, at presentaion level, data is available in same way.

Comment: If you're creating a protocol (which is in 99.99 % or case useless) then GET and POST must be defined before any use of them.
If you refer to GET & POST methods from HTTP protocol, then you're not creating a protocol, thus make it clear what you really speak about.

Comment: Try to read POST values from cin, it is what is said in your link

Comment: @Geoffroy I tried with `scanf("%s", args);` and `getline(cin, args);` with same result : it is waiting for user input (and like it has nothing to read, it blocks).  I "create" a protocol to insert HTML tags in mail unlike mailto is for plain text.

Comment: And I use a HTML form (`<form action="myproto:" method="GET/POST">`) to transmit values with the URL. I use this personal protocol in an Intranet where all employees are using Firefox and Thunderbird.

Comment: Okay, so that's not at all a protocol in fact :)

Comment: @Geoffroy Oh, sorry for the misunderstanding. So now I dont even know what my problem concerns :p (except recover POST values in C++)

Comment: Check the documentation of your web server (apache or whatever)

Comment: Well, I saw [this page](http://shadow2531.com/opera/testcases/mailto/modern_mailto_uri_scheme.html#forms), and I think it's the browser that makes this trick (with POST args) for the mailto protocol, not Thunderbird or others client mail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to give my solution :
I use the [curl executable](http://curl.haxx.se/download.html) (version Win32 - Generic / Win32 2000/XP / binary) for downloading a file contents that contains all my POST values​​. To use this executable from my program, I use `popen()` function.
This works on Windows Seven x64 with MinGW32.

I dont know if it's the best solution, but it works well!